# Is there a way to ignore code style setting in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

As the title suggests, I would like to have a code style (for Kotlin) in place but ignore a specific rule (specifically "Chained method calls").

This rule should simply not apply when using the code formatting functionality and just let the developer judge on a case-by-case basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this with the following configuration inside

`Preferences > Editor > Code Style > Kotlin`:

[image: chaining settings screenshot]

You will also want to activate the setting to preserve your line breaks:

[image: preserve line breaks screen shot]

Comment: If you want the code to be automatically indented when the developer manually moves a method in the chain to a new line, then check "Use continuation indent"

Comment: The problem is that I don't want "Do not wrap" or "Wrap always". I just want the code style formatting to ignore this specific rule.
Sometimes I might want to wrap, sometimes not, depending on the specific code part.

Comment: A setting of "Do not wrap" will preserve whatever wrapping you make when you write the code. If you wrap, it will preserve that, if you don't wrap, it won't do it for you. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Do you have "Keep when formatting > Line breaks" checked?

Comment: Updated my answer to include this step.

Comment: You're welcome - please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by upvoting and accepting helpful answers (which also gives you a small boost to your
reputation ;)

Comment: Please also accept the answer, if it indeed provided the solution.